# local presence dialing in twilio

Tags: salesforce, twilio, twilio-api

We have need to implement local presence dialing in twilio.

**Local Presence Dialing : Be Local use a local caller ID on all outbound calls. match the area code of the caller ID with the area code on the Salesforce record.**

How can we achieve that requirement in twilio?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share some code that you have attempted to get this working?

Comment: @philnash I haven't found any example code for implement the Local Presence dialing in twilio. For that reason i have asked a example like what additional parameters we have need to provide to use Local Presence Dialing feature of twilio.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can try to write the logic to purchase local or international numbers to match your users numbers. I don't know what you're building in or what you've tried so far, so can't specifically help with that. (Though if you have tried something, please feel free to update your question and I'll see how I can help.)

Alternatively, you may like to take a look at [Twilio Proxy](https://www.twilio.com/proxy). It's a [newly announced](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/05/introducing-twilio-proxy.html) feature of Twilio that handles sessions for you between callers. It can do things like local presence dialling, like [Twilio Copilot can for SMS messaging](https://www.twilio.com/copilot).

Proxy is new, so you need to [request access](https://www.twilio.com/proxy#request-access). Let me know if you're interested.